# image not found in media library

Tags: media-library

I've been inadvertently given the keys to a clients website. (I've redesigned an image for their WordPress site, and now they want me to swap the images out) Easy.

Only the old image doesn't show up in the Media Library - and I can't seem to find a reference to it to change it. I've tried over-writing it by using the same name (didn't change).
For what's it's worth: They're using the HTML5 Reset theme and the image is on the main menu (can't seem to find the image that way either appearance > menu)

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

I can only take a guess at this.

Is the image you want to change a background image (using CSS)? - if you goto the page, use your web inspector tool. You should then be able to see where image url is coming from.

Comment: In the event that they found the URL of the image (say http://foo.co.uk/wp-content/themes/foo%20theme/_/IMG/foo.png) where would be able to change the image?

Comment: They would have to use a FTP app, or their CPANEL file browser, locate the picture file and then either use the same filename for the picture, or upload the new picture or change the CSS file by changing the filename and then upload the new picture...